# enabling XDMCP in XFCE w/ GDM (VNC Server in XFCE)

Tags: vnc, linux, xdmcp

Using XFCE4, I'm trying to enable XDMCP for it.

In fact what I'm looking for is to setup a VNC server with TightVNC in a machine running XFCE4.

I already managed to connect via x11vnc but this solution only gives me a VNC session for physical X sessions and I need a virtual one (or whatever it's name is).

I've found that what I need, besides TightVNC and Xinet, is to enable XDMCP, but all info I found is about KDE or Gnome or even just X... what would be the way in XFCE ?

Using Debian Lenny, XFCE4 w/ GDM...

any other useful information please tell me so I can post it right here...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it!
In configuration menu, there's an option for login window and there at remote tab the option for XDMCP is at the bottom, that's why I hasn't noticed it... Thanks!

Comment: I have further questions on VNC but I'll
post them in a new thread...

Answer (score 2):

You can't enable XDMCP in XFCE4. XDMCP is something that is enabled in the display manager, not in a desktop environment. As you didn't tell us which display manager you use (GDM? XDM?), I can't help.

Note that some display managers (e.g. SLIM) don't support XDMCP at all.